# What do the underscored properties mean when you log a JS object in Chrome Devtools

Tags: javascript, logging, console, google-chrome-devtools

See the image below to see what I mean

[image: What do the underscored properties mean when you log a JS object in Chrome Devtools]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that properties are "private", it is developers agreement. 
See more about it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Contributor_s_Guide/Private_Properties#Using_Prefixes

I don't recommend use these properties, because they can change in next Leaflet version (sometimes as I remember it happens).